# How to translate or transition dynamically without using calc() css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms

I need to transform or transition dynamically without using calc(). Previously, i had used `left: calc(100% - 10px)` with `transition: .05s` the transition is not working properly in IE11. So, i need to achieve this in different way. Is this possible to achieve in `transform: translate()` property?

I need to move one span inside div; if I increase the div width, that means the span automatically moves to the left, so I used `calc(100% - 10px)`, here `10px` is the `<span>`'s width.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What do you mean by dynamically? Transition what? Height? Background color? A div? A replaced element?

Comment: @TylerH added more information hope you understand.

Comment: If you can post a snippet with your current code, it will be easier to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is will be possible while using **margin-left** property. Without using calc function, this will helps to calculate left.